# How to connect two Lightsail Instances, so I can fetch data from one instance to other?

Tags: geoserver

I have two instances at Amazon Lightsail. One is at Wordpress and other is at Windows server2016. I have installed geoserver at Windows Server2016 and add some vector and raster layers on that. Using wordpress one website is running. I want to fetch the layers to this website. Ho to do?

Comment: you'll want a WMS client like OpenLayers or Leaflet

Comment: But my question is that,  from my existing website [created by wordpress] how will i use this openlayer link?